# php case statement continue or break depending on value in variable

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, switch-statement, case

So I am wanting to show a certain amount of columns depending on users selection. If a case statement the way forward or is there an other solution.

How Can I do is so that if 1 is selected only the first block is executed, if two cols two blocks executed if 3 then 3 blocks executed and if 4 then 4 blocks executed.

I am want to use a case/some other statement so that I wouldnt end up doing something like

```
if(option = 1){
    echo sidebar 1
}elseif(option = 2){
    echo sidebar 1 
    echo sidebar 2
}elseif(option = 3){
    echo sidebar 1
    echo sidebar 2
    echo sidebar 3
}elseif(option = 4){
    echo sidebar 1
    echo sidebar 2
    echo sidebar 3
    echo sidebar 4
}
```

How could I achieve something like

```
switch($option){
    case 1: (Always executed)
        echo sidebar 1
    case 2: (only executed if $option is 2, 3 or 4)
        echo sidebar 2
    case 3: (only executed if $option is 3 or 4)
        echo sidebar 3
    case 4: (only executed if $option is 4)
        echo sidebar 4
    break;
}
```

Comment: In order to get the sidebar use this ` <?php dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget ' . $i); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample case, you can do something smart like

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $option; ++$i) {
  echo sidebar $i;
}
```

I don't know if it will fit in your actual code.

Comment: Thanks that work to an extent, how can I get the value of the i variable inside the dynamic sidebar where it is currently 1 `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Footer Widget 1' ); ?>`

Comment: Maybe `<?php dynamic_sidebar( "Footer Widget $i" ); ?>`

Comment: In order to get the sidebar use this `<?php dynamic_sidebar('Footer Widget ' . $i); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
$option = 4; //For example
echo sidebar 1
if($option && $option != 1)
{
    for($i = $option; $i <= 4; ++$i)
        echo sidebar $i;
}
```

It will fit in your actual code.